# Weird time behaviour with $_SESSION usage

Tags: php, session, time

I must admit I'm quite newbie in PHP but look at this please:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['mailtime'])){
    $_SESSION['mailtime'] = time();
    echo 'Mail time: '. $_SESSION['mailtime'] .'</br>Time now: ' . time() . '</br>';
    echo 'Since last mail:' . time()-($_SESSION['mailtime']) . ' sec';
}
else{
    echo 'Mail time: '. $_SESSION['mailtime'] .'</br>Time now: ' . time() . '</br>';
    echo 'Since last mail:' . time()-($_SESSION['mailtime']) . ' sec';
}
```

and this give me a result for eg:

```
Mail time: 10
Time now: 16
Since last mail: -10 sec
```

What's wrong with my code? I tried to make

```
$mailtime = $_SESSION['mailtime'];
```

but with shorter variables I get:

```
Mail time:
Time now:
Since last mail: 0 sec
```

Comment: I don't like how you put expressions in echo strings.

Comment: Also I have no clue what part of your code is executed as the code that is setting `$_SESSION['mailtime']` is omitted. Is mail time set in your example or not?

Answer (score 0):

Your example seems somewhat contrived. The PHP `time()` function should return a much higher number:

> **int time()**
> Returns the current time measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

For an example of how to use the `time()` function go to the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php). It shows clearly that **you may be better off using `date()` for your purposes.**

You should be clear about where you are setting `$_SESSION['mailtime']`. In your example the output indicates that the lines you are setting the variable some seconds before you are comparing it to `time()`. To debug, you have to show your code, not just an artificial example.

Comment: This is not really an answer, to his problem, unless you suggest that his example is not what he really sees when he is executing the code (which I think is the case).

Comment: It was just an example, I have big numbers indeed.